# Xcode build succeeds however it does not downloads app on the simulator

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, appium, ios-simulator

Xcode build succeeds however it does not download app on the simulator through terminal.

I am using the below command in mac terminal to build my code, however, the build succeeds but the app does not get downloaded to my ios simulator as it does using the xcode application

```
xcrun xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme "Test App" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=13.2'
```

How can i successfully pull my code from Github and then successfully deploy on ios simulator with few lines?

Comment: This link should help you - https://www.anexinet.com/blog/install-app-ios-simulator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you build your content, run `xcrun simctl install <UDID> <PATH>` to install the app in the sim.  Be sure you have booted it first as well ( which you can also use simctl for).

Comment: i was able to find the path of the app where it downloads, is it going to be a same url? is there a way to add a path where i can download?

Comment: Also, i noticed that i have to open the simulator manually, how can i automatically open the simulator and download the app